# Missing php8.0-fpm sock file

Tags: ubuntu, php, php8.1

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS` and I used the following commands to install php8.0

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php80`

`sudo apt-get install php8`

after running `php -v` it's running the following version: `PHP 8.0.24-SergeyD/2.3 (cli) ( NTS )`

When I check in `/var/run/php/` I can only see the following `.sock` files:

`php7.2-fpm.sock`

`php7.2-fpm.pid`

Why is the `.sock` file missing?  How can I install it?

Comment: install `php8-fpm`?

Comment: btw, Ubuntu 18.04 has already reached its end of life. You should upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Ubuntu 18.04 was removed from Ondřej Surý's PPA on June 15, 2023 as that version of Ubuntu is no longer supported.

If you really must use PHP 8 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, then your only semi-supported way forward would be to use Docker containers. However, if Docker is no longer making their tools available for 18.04, then you'll need to consider updating from 18.04 to something newer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't install it - it is created automatically when PHP-FPM is run. It is created in the location defined in the FPM config.

The valid use-cases for running multiple PHP versions on the same host are very rare. Keeping an unsupported running is not one of them.